# Lock a grid column in place when changing GridViewColumn width

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate for a gridview column, it has 2 items in it, an image and a text block, I want to "lock" the image to the left side of the column, even if the user expand the width of the column, I want the image to stay put.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to Stretch for `GridViewColumnHeader`

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <!--...-->
</ListView>
```

Then your HeaderTemplate can look something like this if you want the `TextBlock` to be centered. *Otherwise just remove the `HorizontalAlignment`*

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" .../>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" .../>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```